# cJSON_Parse() causing parse error for JSON files with more than 50 lines on Renesas MCU with NextX module

Tags: c, parsing, cjson, mcu

I'm working on a project using a Renesas MCU with the NetX module, where I'm utilizing the cJSON library to parse JSON data from a file. On my PC, the parsing works perfectly fine regardless of the size of the JSON file. However, when I deploy the same code to the Renesas MCU, cJSON_Parse() starts throwing parse errors for JSON files with more than 50 lines.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cJSON.h"

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[10240];
    cJSON *json;

    strcpy(buffer, "valid json string");

    json = cJSON_Parse(buffer); // if buffer too long, it can not parse correctly.
    if (json == NULL) {
        const char *error_ptr = cJSON_GetErrorPtr();
        if (error_ptr != NULL) {
            printf("Error before: %s\n", error_ptr);
        }
        cJSON_Delete(json);
        return 1;
    }

    // Process JSON data here...

    cJSON_Delete(json);
    return 0;
}
```

Despite working fine on my PC, cJSON_Parse() starts failing when the JSON string exceeds(if in a file, around 50 lines) on the Renesas MCU with the NetX module. Are there any specific limitations or considerations I should be aware of when using cJSON library on this platform? How can I ensure proper parsing for larger JSON files on this MCU?

PS: suggestions are MCU stack size limitation, but how to configure it?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might add a few details what "a Renesas MCU" means. How much memory is available there? How much heap have you configured? If you increase heap size, does it move the limit for your file size?

Comment: I don't know if `cJSONparse` depends on it (or if it stops when the closing bracket is reached) but your buffer does not contain a terminating 0 byte. The local array is not initialized and `fread` does not add a 0 byte. Therefore you do not pass a valid string to the parsing function.

Comment: You do not test the return value of your `fread()`.  You should verify that it is between 1 and `sizeof(buffer) - 1` (not `sizeof(buffer)`, for in that case you have to assume in that the buffer was not large enough, unless you have advance knowledge of its exact size).  Plus, that ensures that there is space for a null terminator.

Comment: BTW: What error message do you get? Is the mentioned position within your file or some random data?

Answer (score 1):

With acknowledgement to @Gerhardh, who pointed it out in comments, your code does nothing to ensure that the JSON data read into `buffer` are zero terminated.  Specifically,

- local variables, including those of `main()`, are initialized only if you provide an explicit initializer.  You provide none for the `buffer` variable, so all its contents are initially indeterminate. These *can* be zero, but they don't have to be.
- the `fread()` function does not add a terminator after the data it reads.
- you do not manually add a terminator, either.

However, [`cJSON_Parse()` requires its input to be a conventional nul-terminated string](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON?tab=readme-ov-file#parsing-json).  You might happen to get that incidentally, on either your PC or on your MCU, but it is not safe to rely on it.

The number of lines of the input is probably a red herring, except inasmuch as it correlates with the length of the input in bytes.  It is plausible that the MCU happens to ensure, for some unspecified reason, that some number of initial bytes of the stack are zeroed. Files that happen to be shorter would likely, then, be parsed correctly, but longer files probably would not be.  It is plausible that your PC zero-initializes a larger region of the stack, such that the program's flaw does not manifest misbehavior there.

Since you need to check the return value of `fread()` anyway, I'd just use that (on success) to add the needed terminator:

```
        size_t bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp);
        if (bytes_read < 1) {
            // handle error (or empty file) ...
        } else if (bytes_read >= sizeof(buffer)) {
            // handle overlength input ...
        }
        buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
```

Comment: thanks for suggestions. But it is not this fall. I change the simplied code with string. So there is neither file nor '\0' terminator issue.  focus on the cJSON variable size in MCU

Comment: There's also a parse function that takes an explicit length argument that could be used.

Comment: @Gerhardh, `else if`, yes, fixed.  `else`, no -- I am assuming that there is no useful way to recover from either of the two error conditions, such that the code to handle them must ultimately terminate the application.

Answer (score 0):

MCUs typically have much more limited RAM and storage compared to a PC. The buffer size of 1024 bytes may not be sufficient to hold larger JSON files in their entirety, leading to incomplete data being passed to cJSON_Parse(), which could cause parsing errors.

Try out this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cJSON.h"

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    long file_size;
    char *buffer;
    cJSON *json;

    fp = fopen("data.json", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Determine file size
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    // Allocate memory for the entire content
    buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * file_size);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed.\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }

    // Copy the file into the buffer
    fread(buffer, 1, file_size, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    // Ensure the string is null-terminated
    buffer[file_size] = '\0';

    json = cJSON_Parse(buffer);
    if (json == NULL) {
        const char *error_ptr = cJSON_GetErrorPtr();
        if (error_ptr != NULL) {
            printf("Error before: %s\n", error_ptr);
        }
        free(buffer); // Free the allocated memory
        cJSON_Delete(json);
        return 1;
    }

    // Process JSON data here...

    cJSON_Delete(json);
    free(buffer); // Free the allocated memory
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's rather unlikely that the same files fits into 1024 bytes on the Pc but not on the MCU.

Comment: ... but not altogether impossible, @Gerhardh, for some values of "the same".  For example, if the version of the file processed on the PC has Unix-style line terminators, but the one processed on the MCU has Windows-style terminators, then it really might be the case that it fits in the buffer on the PC but not on the MCU.  Note that the OP's program uses `fread()` to read it, so there will be no translation of line terminators.

Comment: just now corrected tip error to: buffer[10240], or even buffer[102400], but still have a parse problem.

Comment: @Siegen again, how much memory is available on your MCU? `buffer[102400]` located on the stack is rather demanding for some embedded micros.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MCU. Sorry, I do not know, could you please tell me how to figure it out? Just now, I enlarge many stack storage in mcu.

Comment: @Siegen you must have some datasheet for your microcontroller. It should mention how much RAM you have. Also, objects created durring parsing your file will not be stored on the stack but will be allocated from the heap. You need to check your project configuraiton about the size of available heap memory. If you have enough RAM you can increase that heap and see if you can parse larger files.

Comment: yes, the heap size is the issue. now the question is solved. Thanks!